# How do i need to modify this select in sql-server to also include players not on any team?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have 3 tables, one for players, one for teams, and one for assigning players to teams. I am trying to find all players not in the chess team. I tried the following

```
SELECT
    TP.intPlayerID
   ,TP.strLastName + ', ' + TP.strFirstName AS strPlayer
FROM 
    TPlayers                    AS TP
        JOIN TTeamPlayers       AS TTP
            JOIN TTeams         AS TT
            ON ( TTP.intTeamID = TT.intTeamID )
        ON ( TP.intPlayerID = TTP.intPlayerID )
WHERE
    --TTP.intTeamID <> 2  no difference noticed
    TTP.intTeamID != 2 --hard code for chess team
ORDER BY
    strPlayer
```

It gave me back the players on other teams, even if they are in the chess team too, and it didn't give me the players that are not on any team at all. I feel as though I should have a subquery somewhere in here, leaning towards the where. I tried using a NOT EXISTS but couldn't get the syntax to work for me. If you want any other info such as the tables or inserts that I am using let me know and I will edit question to include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using NOT IN as follows:

```
create table #Players
(PlayerId int identity(1,1),
Name varchar(10));


create table #Teams
(TeamId int identity(1,1),
Game varchar(30));

create table #TeamPlayers
(TeamId int,
PlayerId int);

insert into #Players (Name)
values ('a'),('b'),('c'),('d'),('e');

select * from #Players;

insert into #Teams (Game)
values ('No Team'),('Cricket'),('Chess'), ('Tennis'),('BasketBall');

select * from #Teams;

insert into #TeamPlayers (TeamId,PlayerId)
values (1,2), (2,1),(3,3),(4,3),(4,4),(5,5), (6,3);

select * from #TeamPlayers;

select * 
from #Players as P
where p.PlayerId not in 
    (
        select p.PlayerId 
        from #Players as P
        inner join #TeamPlayers as tp
        on p.PlayerId=tp.PlayerId
        inner join #Teams as t
        on tp.TeamId =t.TeamId
        where t.TeamId=3
    );
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.